# Index of Substring Prolog

Tags: prolog, substring, swi-prolog

I am using the sub_string function. Since I do not know how many characters before or after, is there any way from running this line of code (or some other method) of finding in a string such as "sdlfkjdonutlsv" what index the substring "donut" starts at? (this is for solving a word search).

```
sub_string(H,_,Length,_,Word)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass in `sub_string(word, N, Len, M, substring)` where you pass in `word` and `substring`, prolog will match `N`, `Len` and `M`. For example

```
[?- sub_string('helloworld',N,L,M,'llo').
    N = 2,
    L = 3,
    M = 5
```